# Hystrix Configuration : isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds

Tags: timeout, hystrix

I'm trying to implement timeInMilliseconds Hystrix.
Added this definition to my method:
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "returnEmptyResponse",
                    commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty(name = "hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "5000")})

Added to my class the relevant annotation: @EnableCircuitBreaker, and relevant dependencies.

I expected that if i didnt get response from my method after 5000 ms, returnEmptyResponse will be called.
It's not happen.
Did anyone know what can it be?

Comment: please post hystrix function and the caller function code.

Comment: protected <T> T returnEmptyResponse() {
  return null;
 }
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "returnEmptyResponse",
    commandProperties = {@HystrixProperty(name = "hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "10")})
protected  <T> T executePostRequest(UriComponents uriComponents, Object request, Class<T> responseBodyClass) {
 ...
 try {
  ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(getURI(uriString), entity, responseBodyClass);
  return responseEntity.getBody();
 } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
  ...
 }
}